# Как заполнить таблицу permission_pore средствами пакета Laratrust во фреймворке Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel5, laravel-5.6, role, laravel5.4

Использую Laratrust для работы с ролями. В принципе кажется понял что к чему и как с ним работать. Через сидеры заполняю таблицы:

- users
- roles
- permissions
- role_user
- permission_user

Таблицы **role_user** и **permission_user** заполняю так:

```
    $user->attachPermissions($permissions);
    $user->attachRoles($role);
```

Но не могу заполнить таким же образом таблицу **permission_role**. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Странно что не получилось ранее

```
$role->attachPermissions($permissions);
```